# binding template view with uibmodal controller

Tags: angularjs, modalviewcontroller

I use uibmodal in one of my controller, and managed to pass data to the modal controller. 
However, once the data has been passed in my modal controller, I can't figure out how to get this data rendered in the modal template.

My main controller:

```
doEdit = function () {
        var modalScope = $scope.$new(false);
        modalScope.roleModel = self.gridApiRoles.selection.getSelectedRows()[0];

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/dialog.html',
                scope: modalScope,
                windowTemplateUrl: 'template/flexModal.html',
                backdrop: 'static',

                resolve: {
                    roleModelScope: function () {
                      return modalScope.roleModel;
                    }
                },

                controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'roleModelScope', DialogEditController],
                controllerAs: 'ctrl'
            });

            modalScope.modalInstance = modalInstance;

            modalInstance.result.then(
                function close(result) {
                    console.info(result);
                },
                function dismiss() {
                    console.info("dialog dismissed");
                }
            );
        }
    };
```

My UibModal controller:

```
let DialogEditController = function ($scope, $rootScope, roleModelScope) {

  let self = this;

  self.$onInit = () => {
    initTest();
  };

  let initTest = () => {
    console.log(roleModelScope.name);
  };
};
```

At this point, roleModelScope.name has been perfectly passed to the modal controller.

My template:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:900px; height:750">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header bg-info">
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        {{roleModelScope.name}}
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use ctrl.roleModelScope but it didn't work neither.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a `roleModelScope` value inside controller `this`(context), so that it will be available for binding on view.

Also your `Modal` controller alias  is `ctrl`, use `{{ctrl.roleModelScope.name}}` inspite of `{{roleModelScope.name}}`.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ctrl.roleModelScope.name}}
</div>
```

**Code**

```
let initTest = () => {
    this.roleModelScope = roleModelScope;
    console.log(roleModelScope.name);
};
```

Comment: well, roleModelScope is the controller modal scope. I guess I need to mention it. I tried anyway your solution, but without success. I also tried ctrl.roleModelScope.name without more success.

Comment: @Piotr___ did you see value in console?

Comment: @Piotr___ please check udpated answer.. My bad..I missed important part in my answer :(

Comment: You made me learn more about the 'this' thing :-). Thank you. It almost worked. I still had to mention the roleModelScope in the html. Just like this: ctrl.roleModelScope.name; And then it works.

Comment: @Piotr___ Glad it helped, upvote if it helped. Thanks :)